How can I add a new border radius definition?
The rounded classes are generated based on following SASS variables (I think)
$rounded: (
  0: 0,
  'sm': $border-radius-root / 2,
  null: $border-radius-root,
  'lg': $border-radius-root * 2,
  'xl': $border-radius-root * 6,
  'pill': 9999px,
  'circle': 50%
);

I'd like to update the above definition by doing something like this
// Keep the originals and change only what I need to change
$rounded: (
  'xl': $border-radius-root * 4, // Updated
  'xxl': $border-radius-root * 6 // Added
);

Do you know how I can achieve this result?

Have you tried out to follow these steps?

@BoussadjraBrahim which steps?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#basic-usage

@BoussadjraBrahim it's surely useful, but it doesn't really explain how to achieve the kind of merging I'm trying to achieve

create new file
src/styles/main.scss
$border-radius-root: 4px; // default

@use 'vuetify' with (
  $rounded: (
    'xl': $border-radius-root * 4, // Updated
    'xxl': $border-radius-root * 6, // Added
  )
);

Then where you define the vuetify plugin, usually src/plugins/vuetify.ts, add the file you just created and remove vuetify/styles
// Styles
import '@/styles/main.scss' // Added
// import 'vuetify/styles' <-- comment this out


Is there a way to avoid redefining the $border-radius-root in order to use its default value directly?

there might be a way to import it from vuetify so you don't have to define it yourself, but I honestly couldn't figure it out.

I tested it and it works, the only thing is that I have to redefine the variable, which is a bummer
